# PHP class doesn't echo another php page at the appropriate place

Tags: php, class

Alright, I'm using a page creating class I found as below but when I want to use a php page -that again includes and uses a class file- for the content it either echoes on the top or the bottom of the page... I even tried to make the page a function() and call it at the $Content string but no use, again it echoed on the top of the page... How can i use a php page as a content in this class, or what should i change to use a php file?

Please keep in mind that I'm new to classes so feel free to assume some beginner mistakes.

```
<?php
class Page {
var $Title;
var $Keywords;
var $Content;

   function Display( ) {
 echo "<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n";
 $this->DisplayTitle( );
 $this->DisplayKeywords( );
 echo "\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n";
 echo $this->Content;
 echo "\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n";
}

   function DisplayTitle( ) {
 echo "<TITLE>" . $this->Title . "</TITLE>\n";
   }

   function DisplayKeywords( ) {
     echo '<META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="' . $this->Keywords . '">';
   }

   function SetContent( $Data ) {
     $this->Content = $Data;
   }
 }
?>
```

Usage:

```
<?php
include "page.class";

$Sample = new Page;

$Content = "<P>I want my php file's contents here.</P>";

$Sample->Title = "Using Classes in PHP";
$Sample->Keywords = "PHP, Classes";
$Sample->SetContent( $Content );

$Sample->Display( );

?>
```

What if I wanted to make the content something like $Content = " < ? echo 'test'; ? >"; I know this isn't valid but what i'm trying to do is something like that or something like $Content = " output of the whateversinhere.php ";. how should I object orient another page therefore getting its contents into a string here?

Comment: well what if, $Content= content(); and function content () is a php code that uses a class then returns a value. so logically content would be the contents of a php file which uses some other class to process an information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should NOT echo anything inside your class, instead the class should have a method getMarkup(), which will return a string containing the whole markup. Then you can echo that string in your view.

Additional tipps:

- variables and method names start with a small letter!
- title and keywords should have getters and setters too
- make your variables private (private $title, etc.)

Comment: I don't see the double output problem.

Answer (score 0):

let me clean this up for you, you will notice some changes:

```
class Page
{
    private $title = 'No Title';
    private $keywords = array();
    private $content = '';

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = (string)$title;
    }

    public function addKeywords($keywords)
    {
        $this->keywords = array_merge($this->keywords, (func_num_args() > 1) ? func_get_args() : (array)$keywords;
    }

    function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    function appendContent($content)
    {
        $this->content .= $content;
    }

    function prependContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content . $this->content;;
    }

    private function display()
    {
        /*
         * Display output here
         */
        echo $this->title;
        echo implode(',',str_replace(',','',$this->title));
        echo $this->contents;
    }
}
```

pretty simple usage:

```
$Page = new Page;
$Page->setTitle("Hello World");
$page->addKeywords("keyword1","keyword2","keyword3","keyword4");

//Content
$this->setContent("World");
$this->prependContent("Hello");
$this->appendContent(".");

//Display
$this->display();
```

Just got to fill in the blanks, you will learn as time goes on that you should not be using html directly within your class, and that you would split the above into several class such as `Head`,`Body`,`Footer`,`Doctype` and have a page class that brings them all together.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Output Control Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

```
<?php
include "page.class";

 $Sample = new Page;

ob_start();
include "foobar.php";//What you want to include.
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$Sample->Title = "Using Classes in PHP";
$Sample->Keywords = "PHP, Classes";
$Sample->SetContent($content);

$Sample->Display( );
?>
```

Comment: Why is it bad? Is there a problem using Output Control? :(